# Ansible task to be run on hosts other than "server_1" or "server_2"

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I'd like to be able to run an ansible task only on hosts NOT matching "server_1" or "server_2".

In semi pseudo code:

```
- name: Set localtime
  file: src=/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC
        dest=/etc/localtime
        state=link
  when: only when hostname is NOT "server_1" or "server_2"
```

Answer (score 2):

To compare hostnames:

```
when: ansible_hostname not in ['server_1', 'server_2']
```

To compare inventory aliases:

```
when: inventory_hostname not in ['server_1', 'server_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
- name: Set localtime
  file: src=/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC
        dest=/etc/localtime
        state=link
  when: ansible_hostname not in [server_1', 'server_2']
```

Comment: Working great! Thanks a lot Arbab!